# How to insert data to database without login, wordpress?

Tags: php, android, wordpress

I create some plugin in Wordpress. This plugin will insert data into the database from the Android App via `POST` and will return the string message. So my question is how to insert data to the database without login in Wordpress? Because user can register via the Android app, but without login first in Wordpress. Also what about the URL action to send data to Wordpress?

This is my simple code.

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cte'; // do not forget about tables prefix

$wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
    'name' => 'Alex',
    'email' => 'alex@example.com',
    'age' => 25
));
```

Comment: The usual method would be an OAuth2 access key to talk to your API, so you'd probably need some OAuth2 API server plugin on your wordpress site

Comment: This looks like what you need https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth2

Comment: @delboy1978uk thank you, I will check it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cte'; // do not forget about tables prefix

$wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
    'name' => 'Alex',
    'email' => 'alex@example.com',
    'age' => 25
));
```

or probably get the wp-load.php with your path where you are putting the code

Comment: this appears to have zero security, so watch out

Comment: @delboy1978uk thank you for your reminder, I create a key to access this, so this URL cannot access without the key.

Comment: where do you set this key?

Comment: I will save the key into a database, and in the Android app, the user must fill the key from WordPress DB. so when the user access the URL has to check first the key.